# SQL execution (#1066)

Tags: sql, error-handling

I have a problem with this code:

```js
SELECT
      produse.DENUMIRE,
      clase.CLASA,
      furnizori.NUME_J,
      furnizori.NUME_F
       
      
FROM furnizori

JOIN produse ON produse.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN produse ON produse.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID


LIMIT 1000
;
```

Error is:
SQL execution (#1066)
Not unique table/alias: 'produse'

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need different aliases for the produse table since it's used twice:

```
SELECT
      p1.DENUMIRE,
      clase.CLASA,
      furnizori.NUME_J,
      furnizori.NUME_F
FROM furnizori
JOIN produse p1 ON p1.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN produse p2 ON p2.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID

ORDER BY p1.DENUMIRE

LIMIT 1000
```

You can adjust the `ORDER BY` clause if you want another order.

Comment: this code it has error (#1055) Unknown column 'clase.CLASA' in 'field list'

Comment: @StericaSt, What does that code mean? (We don't even know which dbms you're using.)

Comment: Perhaps you need to add an ORDER BY? (Since you've got LIMIT.)

Comment: @StericaSt, Yes, but don't you have any explanatory error message/text?

Comment: I changed FROM furnizori with FROM clase and error is: #1054 Unknown column 'furnizori.NUME_J' in 'field list'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106739/discussion-between-jarlh-and-sterica-st).

Comment: Show us your current version of the query. (Edit post.)

Comment: `SELECT
      p1.DENUMIRE,
      clase.CLASA,
      furnizori.NUME_J,
      furnizori.NUME_F
FROM clase
JOIN produse p1 ON p1.ID_CLASA = clase.ID
JOIN produse p2 ON p2.ID_FURNIZOR = furnizori.ID
LIMIT 1000
;`

Comment: This is just too confusing. Which tables are involved? Is it clase, produse and  furnizori?